# How to add a country to the location module?

Tags: 7, location

I have a requirement to add additional countries to the location module.

I need to add England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Island.

I suppose they could be provinces, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Many thanks for any help :)

PS. I would be using the county codes for css so country would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So maybe my question wasn't worded in the best way, but I have found the answer.

All countries in Drupal (at least in 7) are taken from the `/includes/iso.inc` file. This includes Location and Address Field.

You can add countries to this list via `drupal_alter`

An example:

```
<?php
function hook_countries_alter(&$countries) {
  // Elbonia is now independent, so add it to the country list.
  $countries['EB'] = 'Elbonia';
}
?>
```

Putting this in a custom module will enable you to add countries as you require. You *must* use a 2 letter iso code!

Comment: How about country module and countries api module?

Comment: There is a countries (https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) for D7 that does about the same with an interface, but the others are not aplicable for D7.

Comment: What would you suggest for country flag icons?